# How to change dictionary that one key has multiple values to dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary `self._alpha_series`.

I use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self._alpha_series.items())`,

It will become below:

[image]

How to change dataframe like:

[image]

Comment: Do you want an index 1-10 in column 2 or do you want the values from the tuple (nan, 100.5, 24.75266, ...) in column 2?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use:

```
print (df)
         0             1
0  1101.TW    (nan, nan)
1  2227.TW  (nan, 100.5)
2  2887.TW   (nan, 24.7)

df[[1,2]] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.ix[:,1].values.tolist())
print (df)
         0   1      2
0  1101.TW NaN    NaN
1  2227.TW NaN  100.5
2  2887.TW NaN   24.7
```

Comment: Looks like they want an index from 1-10 in column 2?

Comment: Yes, but OP mentioned `looks like` and I am not sure what does it mean.